# In C#, What is Best Way to Store Object Values for Class To Access Dynamically?

Tags: c#

## Background

I come from the Javascript world. In my scenario, I want to store data that would look like the following when in JSON:

```
let operations = {
    "a" : {
        "key" : "a"
        "desc" : "Add"
        "response" : "+"
    },
    "s" : {
        "key" : "s"
        "desc" : "Subtract"
        "response" : "-"
    },
    "m" : {
        "key" : "m"
        "desc" : "Multiply"
        "response" : "*"
    },
    "d" : {
        "key" : "d"
        "desc" : "Divide"
        "response" : "/"
    },
}
```

I'd like to be able to access it dynamically, so that if I have a variable, `currentOp = "a"`, I can use that variable to access it. In Javascript, I'd write:

```
let description = operations[currentOp].desc
```

## In C#

Inside my main class, I tried out making a tuple, then accessing:

```
public (
    (string desc, string key, string responseChar) a,
    (string desc, string key, string responseChar) s,
    (string desc, string key, string responseChar) m,
    (string desc, string key, string responseChar) d
) ops = (
    ("Add", "a", "+"),
    ("Subtract", "s", "-"),
    ("Multiply", "m", "*"),
    ("Divide", "d", "/")
);
```

I can access it when using dot notation:

```
ops.a.desc
```

I get errors if I try to use bracket notation:

```
ops[curOp].desc
```

So then I tried making a separate class:

```
public class Operations {
    static public (string userOption, string userChar, string responseChar) a { get; } = ("a - Add", "a", "+");
    static public (string userOption, string userChar, string responseChar) b { get; } = ("s - Subtract", "s", "-");
    static public (string userOption, string userChar, string responseChar) c { get; } = ("m - Multiply", "m", "*");
    static public (string userOption, string userChar, string responseChar) d { get; } = ("d - Divide", "d", "/");
}
```

But when accessing again, it works with dot notation, but fails with bracket notation.

## Question

What am I doing wrong here, and am I missing a better way?

#### Notes:

I did play about with ExpandoObject, but I couldn't get that to initiate values with a single line, so wasn't able to make it a static property of the class.

Comment: You would probably want to use a `Dictionary(TKey, TValue)`, where `TKey` is `string` and `TValue` is `Operations`.

Comment: Could you expand on that, please? I'm not sure what TValue is Operations means.

Comment: I'd recommend using a `record` rather than a tuple if the type isn't a one-off (`record Operation(string Description, string Key, string ResponseChar)`) and then something like `Dictionary<string, Operation> ops = new Operation[] { new("Add", "a", "+"), new("Subtract", "s", "-"), ... }.ToDictionary(o => o.Key);`. (The `Dictionary` can also be initialized directly rather than converting an array, but not having to repeat the `Key` makes things more reliable.) JavaScript effectively treats all objects as dictionaries; in C# they are separate concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, You are using a tuple and trying to access data using square brackets.

In the case of a tuple, [] is an indexer. With the help of square brackets, you can access elements at a particular location.

like,

```
var description = ops[0].desc; //Add
```

When you try using `.a`, you read the description value by the tuple's field name.

```
var description = ops.a.desc
                   |   |
                   |   + Tuple field name
                   + Tuple
```

Because you are trying to access the value by field name, the second approach is working fine.

In the first approach, it will start working if you pass an index instead of a field name.

---

An elegant way is to create a class called `Operation`,

```
public class Operation
{
   public string Key { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public string Response { get; set; }

   public Operation(string key, string desc, string response)
   {
      this.Key = key;
      this.Description = desc;
      this.Response = response;

   }
}
```

Now create a dictionary that will store the key and instance of the `Operation` class,

```
Dictionary<string, Operation> dict = new Dictionary()
{
    {"a", new Operation("a", "Add", "+")},
    {"s", new Operation("s", "Subtract", "-")},
    {"m", new Operation("m", "Multiply", "*")},
    {"d", new Operation("d", "Division", "/")},
}
```

Now access value using an appropriate key,

```
var result = dict["a"].Description;
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I don't know the index. I will have in hand, a string "a". I don't know if that is index 0, or 1, or 2.

Comment: @Kelderic, I updated my answer. Kindly check

Comment: That is great. It's more readable than using a dictionary with nested tuple inside. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## Another Answer

Prasad's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73157294/2111901) for this works, and, but it does require both a sub class and a dictionary. If we use nested dictionaries, then we don't need the class. So here is another option, for reference, for anyone else coming to this answer:

```
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> ops = new() {
        {
            "a",
            new Dictionary<string, string> {
                { "desc", "a - Add" },
                { "key", "a" },
                { "response", "+" }
            }
        },
        {
            "b",
            new Dictionary<string, string>{
                { "desc", "s - Subtract" },
                { "key", "s" },
                { "response", "-" }
            }
        },
        {
            "m",
            new Dictionary<string, string>{
                { "desc", "m - Multiply" },
                { "key", "m" },
                { "response", "*" }
            }
        },
        {
            "d",
            new Dictionary<string, string>{
                { "desc", "d - Divide" },
                { "key", "d" },
                { "response", "/" }
            }
        }
    };

var description = ops["a"]["desc"];
```

Comment: this is a terrible approach, the other answer is much more C#-like. `dynamic` in C#  is rarely a good idea and should be only used when you're out of options (almost never). That long line of .Get*().Get... looks terrible and will perform abysmally bad

Comment: I've changed it to be nested dictionaries instead, which removes the need for the workarounds at the end.

Comment: it's equally bad with dictionaries (dynamic is a Dictionary under the hood). Why not a custom class as in the other answer? Dictionary lookup takes longer and is not structured - intellisense won't help. Classes can also add a method that does the actual operation, so you woudn't get some weird bug where the user sees one thing and the output of their operation is not correct